# how to display address in my label , when i press any pin in my map

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have one map view which have some latitude and longitude and it will display with map pins. And I have one label called `address.label.text`. What I need is?

when ever I press  any `latitude and longitude` pins in my map I need to display the address of that `latitude and longitude` in `my label`

How to do that???

Thanks !!

Comment: Mapkit or Google map ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to assign your controller as `MapView` delegate and implement this method:

[func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:)

It will be called when you tap your pin. And from `MKAnnotationView` you can get your annotation, which allow you to get it's coordinates.

Something like this:

```
class MyController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
  }

  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let coordinate = view.annotation?.coordinate {
      myLabel.text = "\(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)"
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, It little bit clear. I am not well good in iOS. i am learner. So, in that ` optional func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView)`... what code i need to place .....to get the address, when i press any pin

Comment: @user5513630, I've updated my answer with code example. Put this code to your controller's class and rename myLabel/mapVeiw to your outlet names. In my example I fill label with such template "lat, long".

Answer (score 0):

To get the address from a lat/long you need to use a reverse geocode function.

```
func getPlacemarkFromLocation(location: CLLocation) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks: [CLPlacemark], error) in
            // Do something with placemarks
    })
}
```

And then call this using:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let coordinate = view.annotation?.coordinate {
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitiude, longitude: coordinate.longitude) 
        getPlacemarkFromLocation(location)          
    }
}
```

The `CLPlacemark` instances contain the address details you're after.

Comment: You need to write the code to take the address from the CLPlacemark and put it into your label. This is just showing you how to get the address, the rest will depend on your needs.